# django verbose_name of proxy model

Tags: django

The verbose name of a proxy model does not use the verbose name of its parent class:

```
# fooapp_time.models

class Activity(Model):
    class Meta(AppMeta):
        verbose_name = 'Aktivität'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Aktivitäten'
```

Here the child class:

```
import fooapp_time.models

class ChildActivity(fooapp_time.models.Activity):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

If I use ChildActivity._meta.verbose_name it is not 'Aktivität' like it should, but 'activity'.

How can I get the verbose_name of the parent class?

Django version: 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution myself:

```
class ChildActivity(fooapp_time.models.Activity):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name=fooapp_time.models.Activity._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural=fooapp_time.models.Activity._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

Better solutions are welcome.